# Android Fragments not showing up Text view and internal elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-framelayout

I am new to android.I created a tablayout and a viewpager with two fragments.I have elements/items in my created Detail Fragment and a TextView in my measure fragment but when i run the code on my mobile,nothing is shown in my fragment.I haven't java code of my fragment.Everything works fine on the tablayout..i can switch between the tab but nothing is being shown in my fragments...why is that happening?

**My Activity:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.update">




                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   >

                    <!--<include android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>-->

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/update_screen_toolbar"
                        layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:id="@+id/name_age_gender"
                        android:background="#d3d3d3"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/update_screen_toolbar"/>



                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                        app:tabMode="fixed"
                        app:tabGravity="fill">

                    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA code for activity**

```
package com.example.update;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class UpdateDetail extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);



        tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new DetailFragment()," DETAIL");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new MeasureFragment(),"MEASURE");


        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }


}
```

**code for DetailFragment:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.DetailFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
     <Button
            android:id="@+id/expandableButton4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#066da1"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
            android:onClick="expandableButton4"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="Expand/Collapse Android Example"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

        <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/expandableLayout4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton4"
            android:background="#90066da1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:ael_duration="400"
            app:ael_expanded="false"
            app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
            app:ael_orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Implements the expand and collapse by sliding logic for a top or a bottom view in a two children view  or layout or any widgets composition.
                 Implements the expand and collapse by sliding logic for a top or a bottom view in a two children view  or layout or any widgets composition." />
        </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/ go through this link it definitly works

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
public class FriendshipParentFragment extends Fragment {


@BindView(R.id.tabs)
TabLayout tabs;

@BindView(R.id.viewpager)
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friendship_parent, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    initTabs();
    return view;
}


private void initTabs(){

    viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabs.getTabAt(0).setText("Tab1");
    tabs.getTabAt(1).setText("Tab2");
    tabs.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent), ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorBottomNavigationPrimary));
    tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.white));
    tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(4);
}


public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new FollowersFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FollowFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

}

xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="owo.owocar.driver.OrdersParentFragment">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: why is such problem arising?...when i used just a toolbat,a tab layout and a view pager....everything worked fine?

Comment: @Jason can't run your code right now. try my approach its doing fine ;)